# Matrix power for sparse matrix in python

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, linear-algebra, sparse-matrix

I am trying to find out a way to do a matrix power for a sparse matrix M: M^k = M*...*M k times where * is the matrix multiplication (numpy.dot), and *not element-wise multiplication*.

I know how to do it for a normal matrix:

```
import numpy as np
import scipy as sp
N=100
k=3
M=(sp.sparse.spdiags(np.ones(N), 0, N, N)-sp.sparse.spdiags(np.ones(N), 2, N, N)).toarray()
np.matrix_power(M,k)
```

How can I do it for sparse M:

```
M=(sp.sparse.spdiags(np.ones(N), 0, N, N)-sp.sparse.spdiags(np.ones(N), 2, N, N))
```

Of course, I can do this by recursive multiplications, but I am wondering if there is a functionality like matrix_power for sparse matrices in scipy.
Any help is much much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`**` has been implemented for `csr_matrix`.  There is a `__pow__` method.

After handling some special cases this `__pow__` does:

```
            tmp = self.__pow__(other//2)
            if (other % 2):
                return self * tmp * tmp
            else:
                return tmp * tmp
```

For sparse matrix, `*` is the matrix product (`dot` for ndarray).  So it is doing recursive multiplications.

---

As `math` noted, `np.matrix` also implements `**` (`__pow__`) as matrix power.  In fact it ends up calling `np.linalg.matrix_power`.

`np.linalg.matrix_power(M, n)` is written in Python, so you can easily see what it does.

For `n<=3` is just does the repeated `dot`.

For larger `n`, it does a binary decomposition to reduce the total number of `dot`s.  I assume that means for `n=4`:

```
result = np.dot(M,M)
result = np.dot(result,result)
```

The sparse version isn't as general.  It can only handle positive integer powers.

You can't count on `numpy` functions operating on spare matrices.  The ones that do work are the ones that pass the action on to the array's own method.  e.g. `np.sum(A)` calls `A.sum()`.

Comment: You might want to have a look at this if you have boolean sparse matrix and intend to compute the transitive closure (connectedness): https://ac.els-cdn.com/S0304397505008546/1-s2.0-S0304397505008546-main.pdf?_tid=4cf2407e-de8f-11e7-b0b6-00000aacb35f&acdnat=1513009451_9b447acd7a2c71ea8521617899e4600b

Comment: I hope your answer needs an update. The first thing we see on https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/sparse.html is "`x * y` no longer performs matrix multiplication, but element-wise multiplication (just like with NumPy arrays). To make code work with both arrays and matrices, use `x @ y` for matrix multiplication."

Comment: Welp, looks like `__pw__` is just an element-wise power now

Comment: @MadPhysicist, yes `scipy.sparse` is trying to shed its `np.matrix` legacy.  I'm happy to use `@`, but have yet to create a `csr_array` :)

Answer (score 3):

You can also use `**` notation instead of `matrix_power` for numpy matrix :

```
a=np.matrix([[1,2],[2,1]])
a**3
```

Out :

```
matrix([[13, 14],
        [14, 13]])
```

try it with scipy sparse matrix.