# Sparse matrix matrix power in python

Tags: python, matrix, sparse-matrix

I'm trying to convert my dense matrix code to coexist with sparse matrices as it should give me a nice speed up. For dense matrices I have:

```
np.dot(np.linalg.matrix_power(TM, steps), p0)
```

Where TM is a square large matrix (1024x1024, or larger) and steps is the amount of times I would like to multiply TM by itself, typically ~ 1000. p0  is a vector whose sum is 1.

I can't figure out how to do this for sparse matrices, so instead i'm left with:

```
TM = sp.sparse.csc_matrix(TM)
p0 = sp.sparse.csc_matrix(p0)

for i in range(steps):
    p0 = sp.sparse.csr_matrix.dot(TM,p0)

p0 = p0.todense()
```

Which of course causes a slow down. Is there a faster way to do matrix multiplications of this magnitude with sparse matrices?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Matrix power for sparse matrix in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28702416/matrix-power-for-sparse-matrix-in-python)

Comment: It does look like that's a duplicate, but it also doesn't look like it's any better (i.e. internally the `__pow__` operator does the same thing)