# Memory issues with creating an adjacency matrix using Coo-matrix

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

Hi i am trying to generate an adjacency matrix with a dimension of about 24,000 from a CSV with two columns showing combinations of pairs of genes and a column of 1's to indicate a present interaction....My goal is to have it be square and populated with zeros for combinations not in the two columns

I am using the  following Python script

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.sparse import coo_matrix

l, c, v = np.loadtxt("biogrid2.csv", dtype=(int), skiprows=0, delimiter=",").T[:3, :]
m =coo_matrix((l, (v-1, c-1)), shape=(v.max(), c.max()))

m.toarray()
```

and it runs ok until encountering the following errorIt seems

```
File "/home/charlie/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/scipy/sparse/base.py", line 1184, in _process_toarray_args
    return np.zeros(self.shape, dtype=self.dtype, order=order)

MemoryError
```

Any ideas about how to get around the memory limit in Scipy

Thanks

Comment: Will this help? https://stackoverflow.com/a/8980156/4909087

Comment: It created `m` ok.  The toarray step hits the memory limit.

Comment: What do you want to do with the array created by `m.toarray`?  Because there are very few good reasons to turn an sparse array to dense, especially since it usually causes memory errors.

Comment: i want to basically use it to perform enrichment analyses of cancer gene expression so i want to use it as a giant adjacency matrix...not wedded to dense arrays...just want to have a matrix i can perform analyses on and eventually access the final matrix to perform survival analyses on

Comment: The important part of the question is what *specific* types of analysis you want to do.  Eigen-analysis?  Linear algebra?  Basic boolean math?  Most of us have no idea how to do genetics, but we can talk math all day.

Comment: In short, I have about 160 vectors of about 23000 expression levels (compared to baseline) in people with brain cancer ....i want to put these levels into the nodes of the adjacency matrix and change the edge strengths using a random walk type paradigm, then take the edge weights, and analyze them as covariates

Comment: So basically you need to do matrix dot products for the random walk and covariance martrix, but don't really need an eigen-analysis of the data.  Correct?  Remember, our common language here is math.  I don't know anything about cancer except it sucks.

Comment: Yes this is correct.....i just want to put some weights on the nodes of this matrix based on weights from the vectors i have and then perform a random walk and export the edge weights in a csv file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely what you want isn't `m.toarray` but `m.tocsr()`.  a `csr` matrix can do simple linear algebra (like `.dot()` and matrix powers) natively, for instance this works:

```
m.tocsr()
random_walk_2 = m.dot(m)
random_walk_n = m ** n  
# see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28702416/matrix-power-for-sparse-matrix-in-python
```

Covariance should be implementable as well, but I'm not sure what the specific implementation would be without seeing what your current process is.

EDIT:  To turn the output back into a simpler format to read out to `csv`, you can follow up by returning to `coo` with `.tocoo()`

```
m.tocoo()
out = np.c_[m.data, m.row, m.col].T
np.savetxt("foo.csv", out, delimiter=",") 
# see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6081008/dump-a-numpy-array-into-a-csv-file
```

Answer (score 0):

The function `toarray()` will convert your 24000*24000 sparse matrix (`coo_matrix`) into a dense array of 24000*24000 (assuming you are loading `int`) which needs in terms of memory at least

24000*24000*4 = around 2,15Gb.

To avoid using so much memory you should avoid converting to dense matrix (using `toarray()`) and do your operations with sparse matrix

If you need your matrix squared you can just do `m*m` or `m.multiply(m)` and you will get a sparse matrix.

To save your matrix you have several option.

Simplest one is NPZ see https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.19.0/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.save_npz.html or [Save / load scipy sparse csr_matrix in portable data format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8955448/save-load-scipy-sparse-csr-matrix-in-portable-data-format)

If you want to get your result as your initial CSV file coo_matrix has attributes

> data COO format data array of the matrix
>
> row COO format row index array of the matrix
>
> col COO format column index array of the matrix

see https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.coo_matrix.html

which can be used to create the CSV file.

Comment: I tried this and it seems to work but how do i export the matrix to a CSV or other similar file to work with it